# How does a boost converter power the oscillating circuit and load at the same time?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, load, high-current, astable

so I've put together a boost converter circuit of my own and I have a problem, I want my boost converter to output reasonably high current but whenever I connect a high current load - the astable multiple vibrator I'm using to switch the boost circuit on and off gets cut off from the power supply, which is a 3.7v battery, my goal is to achieve 5v at 4 amps max... Please help me, and please ask me to specify anything you need me to. Thank you[image]

It's a 26650 Li-ion cell - 3.7v 5000mah

Comment: A schematic would be a good start.

Comment: If you're drawing 4A at 5V from your load (20W) you need to be able to pull 20W from your source (the battery). If your battery can't do that the whole thing will shut down. Also, if you have a set duty cycle and no regulation, the output voltage will drop as you apply load. Yes, a schematic will help, but we also need to know about your battery.

Comment: I've added the schematic and battery specs

Comment: The schematic is "messy" therefore difficult to understand. Read this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics/28255#28255  to learn how to draw schematic properly. So that it will look more like: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Power-inverter-circuit.png  With GND at bottom, transistors with names and part numbers etc. Also: you're not going to get a proper stable 5V (like to charge your phone perhaps?) out of this circuit. **It will not happen**. Because there's no voltage regulation feedback loop.

Comment: To stress what @Bimpelrekkie said: your schematic isn't acceptable, because it doesn't even name its components... Instead of saying "the third transistor from the top", we want to be able to talk about "R2", for example. Also, your photograph is terrible. [Here's](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/how-to-add-a-schematic-if-my-mobile-device-cant-run-the-schematics-editor) a post on helping you make better photos.